# MongoDB/PHP One per category

Tags: php, mongodb, database

i have a table like this one:

```
# TABLE IN DB
| Cat | Date    | ... datas ... |
| 1   | 11-02   | data2
| 2   | 11-04   | data2
| 1   | 12-01   | data1
| 2   | 12-01   | data1
| 2   | 12-03   | data3
| 2   | 12-04   | data4
```

My challenge is to get one entry per category and select a specific data (here we select data1). Example of output:

```
# TABLE RESULT
| Cat | Date    | ... datas ... |
| 1   | 11-02   | data2
| 2   | 11-04   | data2
```

Actually i'm geting all category number in an array and all datas in another array.
Then i create two loops "foreach":

```
foreach ($array_cat as $cat){
   foreach($array_data as $data){
        MONGO_FIND_HERE...
   }
}
```

Because the collection is very large and there are lots of cat and datas, this can make around 1000-5000 queries and takes between 10s and 20s to complete.

How can i make this faster, sorry i'm new with MongoDB but i love it :)

**EDIT 1: Simple example**

```
| Cat | Date    | ... datas ... |
| 1   | 11-02   | data2
| 2   | 11-04   | data2
| 1   | 12-01   | data1
| 2   | 12-01   | data1
| 2   | 12-03   | data3
| 2   | 12-04   | data4
```

How can i have only one entry per category with the lastest date and the "data2" ? What structure/architecture should i use ?

```
# TABLE RESULT
| Cat | Date    | ... datas ... |
| 1   | 12-04   | data2
| 2   | 12-04   | data2
```

What mecanism should i use ? How to do it without using "for loop" ? We have the array: array(1,2) knowing the which category exists.
Better :=) ?

Comment: You might want to start using a hierarchy. You can store up to 16 MB in a document in MongoDB 1.4+ (not sure about the version number...).
Also, if you really want to stick with this example, you might want to start using the 'stored procedures'.

Comment: Why do ytou need 5000 items in one page? @benqus MongoDB has no stored procedures.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your result? I am confused by what your really trying to do. So you pick out a category then you want some data in another table? What is an `entry` per category? You mean your trying to do a distinct?

Comment: @Sammaye http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution#Server-sideCodeExecution-Storingfunctionsserverside http://pointbeing.net/weblog/2010/08/getting-started-with-stored-procedures-in-mongodb.html I personally use them at home in my MongoDB server. You need to save your function in the db.system.js collection...

Comment: @benqus Those are executed within the inbuilt JS engine within Mongo so they are not technically server side. The new aggregation framework is more server side. Plus those must be `eval`ed which is not suported throughout most of MongoDB including sharding and many many many other things.

Comment: @benqus Those functions are only truely supported from MRs, as such they do not have the same propeties as normal stored procedures.

Comment: @benqus You should, I stress, should try to avoid using any JS within the mongo queries. Many many many people will stress this to you due to scalability problems and speed problems, especially with $where, infact I saw a JIRA to ban $where in the new aggregation framework entirely earlier.

Comment: It's complicate to explain but i'll try in a different way.

Comment: I have edited my post, ty to all of you trying to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

> My challenge is to get one entry per category and select a specific data (here we select data1).

It sounds like you want [distinct](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Distinct) for that:

```
> db.runCommand({distinct: "coll", key: "category", query : {datas: "data1"}})
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.command.php for a PHP example.

> How can i have only one entry per category with the lastest date and the "data2" ?

If you know the latest date (e.g., querying for 12-04), you can use distinct again:

```
> db.runCommand({distinct: "coll", key: "category", query : {date: "12-04", datas: "data2"}})
```

If the latest date could vary on category, you'll need to use the aggregation framework: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/.

> What structure/architecture should i use ?

It's kind of difficult to know based on this information, I'm not really sure what you're storing (what's data?), how much of it there is (e.g., how many categories per data or dates per data) or if this is the kind of query your app will generally be doing.